# how to disable yarn in hadoop 2.4?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I need to setup HDFS for SPARK, but do not want to enable YARN. How do I go about this?

Is it enough to specify this in etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Do I still need to start Yarn using sbin/start-yarn.sh after sbin/start-dfs.sh??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try using start-mapred.sh

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want mapreduce.framework.name=classic

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Yarn and you have installed it, just stop the service and never boot it.

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager stop
sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver stop
```

Answer (score -1):

You also need this in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>local</value>
</property>

Value is "local" for MR1 and "yarn" for YARN.
```

Comment: "2.x doesn't have full compatibility for MapReduce", uh ? what ?

Comment: @Junayy It seems he has installed apache's default distribution of hadoop. He might not have the services, which are created when installing cloudera's distribution

Comment: @JUnayy Sorry, I meant if he require MR1 and if he has installed hadoop 2.x, he may face compatibility issues